# Removing slashes from array

Tags: php, firebase

Firebase is kicking my a**. I'm trying to a column (tokens) from the users table using php

I set the todo path

```
  $todoPath = 'users/'.$userId.'';
```

get the data

```
  $response = $fb->get($todoPath);
```

and get this $response:

```
 {"lastName":"Sengbe","location":{"name":"San Francisco,    California","id":"114952118516947"},"timezone":"-7","birthday":"06/25/1978","-  J445njkymYw9INQcvAi":{"lastName":"Bond","location":{"name":"San Francisco,   California","id":"114952118516947"},"tokens":2,"timezone":"-7","birthday":"06/25/1978","userName":"whosesse","name":"James Sengbe","verified":"true","provider":"facebook","gender":"male","email":"james@bond.com","firstName":"James"},"userName":"whosesse","name":"james Bond","verified":"true","provider":"facebook","gender":"male","email":"James@bond.com","firstName":"James"}
```

Now I want to grab just the token from this. Nothing I've tried works

tried

```
 $tokens=$response->{'tokens'}

 $tokens=$response['tokens'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `json_decode` to make an object out of the json string.

```
$response = json_decode($fb->get($todoPath));

var_dump($response->tokens);
```

Comment: @user2320607 Perhaps if you realised the "doesn't work" is completely useless in terms of determining the problem, you might get more helpful answers. (i.e.: Why doesn't it work? What output is obtained from a var_dump? How does this contrast with what you were expecting?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` with second argument `true` for making associative array then parse array

```
$json = json_decode($response,true);

$tokens = $json["-  J445njkymYw9INQcvAi"]["tokens"]; //based on your response

echo $tokens;
```

Output:

```
2
```